# Project with scala module not compile under linux

Tags: scala, playframework

I try to run this project https://github.com/mashup-fm/playframework-oauthprovider.git with scala module. I add scala module to dependencies. I get hang after compile. I get problem only on linux.
Under Mac project is running normally. Browser opening connection but didn't get response.
Here is log http://pastebin.com/B2ab4MCh

If i run "play precompile" same situation.

Comment: The link provided to the project doesn't work, the log provided is incomplete, question has low quality. Hard to be able to answer this, it should be removed or edited and fixed.